# Firefox can't find the file at chrome://autoform/skin/autoform.css

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

I need to get css and images of skin folder or some files from content folder, but Firefox throughs **File not found error** .

Here my chrome.manifest.xml file...

```
content autoform jar:chrome/autoform.jar!/chrome/content/
content autoform jar:chrome/autoform.jar!/chrome/content/ contentaccessible=yes
overlay chrome://browser/content/browser.xul chrome://autoform/content/browser.xul

locale autoform fr-FR jar:chrome/autoform.jar!/locale/fr-FR/
locale autoform en-US jar:chrome/autoform.jar!/locale/en-US/

skin autoform classic/1.0 jar:chrome/autoform.jar!/skin/
```

Comment: i don't know still i can't able get the content of skin or content folder..

Answer (score 0):

i think your manifest is messed up. you also cannot have duplicate content autiform tomake it contentaccesible

try this:

```
content autoform ./
content autoform_ca ./ contentaccessible=yes
overlay chrome://browser/content/browser.xul chrome://autoform/content/browser.xul

locale autoform fr-FR ./locale/fr-FR/
locale autoform en-US ./locale/en-US/

skin autoform classic/1.0 ./skin/
```

now can access by `chrome://autoform/skin/autoform.css` or if you need content accessible then use `chrome://autoform_ca/skin/autoform.css`

im not so sure about your overlay line